# Hiding Facebook Chat when app loads

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-chat, facebook-ui

i made a Flash Facebook app with wmode="direct" and i followed facebook tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/hideflashcallback/ and everything works perfect, my flash object gets replaced by an screenshot of it.
The problem is if the player first loads the application with a chat window opened, as the application will never be shown and he won't realize that it is because he has the chat opened. I checked Jetpack Joyride (https://apps.facebook.com/jetpackjoyride) and many other apps and all of them seem to minimize (hide) all the user chat windows, so they won't face that problem. Then, if you open a window, theirs game get replaced with a screenshot like it should.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!